# How are non-triangular wavefront meshes handled?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mesh

I have a wavefront loader, however it only works with triangular meshes.

I have been trying to think how to handle faces with arbitrarily many vertices but I have no idea how they are to be handled as ultimately everything needs to be given to the GPU as triangles and I cannot think fo a way to mape any arbitrary n-gon to triangles.

Like I know how to convert a quadrilateral to two triangles, but my way won't work for quintalaterals for example.

Comment: All convex n-gons can be represented using a triangle fan, using the first vertex as the centre of the fan and every other vertex (1+n), this is assuming the vertices are CCW order.

Comment: If you have nonconvex polygons, you would need to perform [triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation), e.g. using an ear clipping algorithm. I'm not sure how nonplanar nonconvex polygons are usually handled.